# Asset Upload Form Field Error States

Tags: templating, form, error-message

I currently have an asset upload field, but I'm trying to make it call errors back if the image isn't an extension that's set within the field, allowing users to understand why the form didn't save.

```
  {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {% from _self import errorList %}


        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Featured Image</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input id="inputGroupFile01" type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="fields[networkImage]">
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on error calling for this certain scenario? Or a catch-all error for the form field would be great!